# Запущенно или запущено?

Tags: орфография

1) Из словаря: запущенное имение, имение **запущено** (от глагола запустить - оставить без внимания).

2) В наречиях пишется две буквы НН: **запущенно.**

Он жил (как?) запущенно.  Убиравшие со стола девушки выглядели (как?) запущенно.

3) Вопросы возникают при выборе Н/НН **в именной части сказуемого** (наречие  или краткая форма). Да и явная краткая форма иногда пишется по образцу прилагательного с двумя НН.

Примеры:

В доме стало запущенно, под шкафом пыль каталась.

Все запущенно и старо. Как все запущенно!  Катя поняла, что не все так запущено. Мы привыкли жаловаться, что в России все запущено.

Для верности надо бы еще скрасть зверя саженей хоть пяток ― больно **запущенно**, раздрызганно ружье.

Вопрос: В каких предложениях выбор Н/НН сделан неверно и почему?

Comment: *Как всё запущено!* Здесь **было** неверно.

Comment: В доме всё запущено. В доме стало запущенно.  По-разному пишется? А ружье запущенно - это правильно? И можно ли писать: всё запущенно и старо? Это что, прилагательное,  не причастие?

Comment: *Всё запущенно и стАро* — да, если я правильно понимаю, это краткие прилагательные. Всё каково? Просто если написать с одной Н как краткое причастие, тогда тогда будет странно соседство разных частей речи, прилагательного и причастия.

Comment: *В доме всё запущено. В доме стало запущенно. По-разному пишется?* По-моему, именно так, по-разному. Но чтобы объяснить хорошо почему, надо подумать... Мне кажется, что если в первой фразе ещё может быть второй вариант с прилагательным, то во втором не может быть такого же второго с причастием.

Comment: А насчёт ружья: так, я думаю, может быть, как у Вас. Но ничуть не хуже там причастия с одной Н.

Comment: а если это глагол? например Сегодня в реку было запущен(н)о? 200 кг рыбы

Answer (score 2):

```
 Вопросы возникают при выборе Н/НН в именной части сказуемого 
  (наречие или краткая форма). Да и явная краткая форма иногда пишется
  по образцу прилагательного с двумя НН
```

Если это наречие, вопросов не возникает. Наречие на -о всегда образуется от 
 полных прилагательных, а в отглагольных прилагательных пишется -нн-, если они образуются от глагола соверш. вида: запущенный-запущенно.

Причастие от прилагательного отличить сложнее, конечно, потому что в данном прилагательном ещё присутствует глагольность. Запустить - довести до запустения, упадка, расстройства.Причастие здесь можно узнать по присутствию деятеля или обстоятельства действия: В доме всё запущено старыми хозяевами. В доме всё давно запущено.

Если же субъекта действия или обстоятельства нет, то это прилагательное со значением "находящийся в упадке, в плохом состоянии".

В доме стало запущенно (всё в упадке), под шкафом пыль каталась.

Все запущенно (в упадке) и старо. Как все запущенно! Катя поняла, что не все так (что сделано?)запущено (нами). Мы привыкли жаловаться, что в России все (что сделано?) запущено (кем-то приведено в запущение).

Для верности надо бы еще скрасть зверя саженей хоть пяток ― больно запущенно, раздрызганно ружье.Ружьё ( какое?)запущенное, раздрызганное(в плохом состоянии)-прилагательное.

```
   В доме всё запущено. В доме стало запущенно. По-разному пишется?
   А ружье запущенно - это правильно? И можно ли писать: всё запущенно и 
   старо? Это что, прилагательное, не причастие?
```

В доме всё запущено и  В доме всё запущенно - оба варианта возможны, смотря что автор имеет в виду: или "здесь всё запустили", или"здесь всё в плохом состоянии".

"Всё запущенно и старо"  - однородные члены ( всё каково?) прилагательные,значит, -нн-

Comment: В доме всё (каково?) запущено - краткое причастие? В доме  стало (как?) запущенно - наречие?  Обычно по производителю действия и Т.п. определяется прямое или переносное значение: настойка выдержана - она спокойна и выдержанна. Такое прилагательное получено из причастия, своего глагола оно не имеет. А здесь в словаре обозначены как самостоятельные оба глагола: запустить 1 (привести в движение) и запустить 2  (оставить без внимания), переносного значения уже нет.

Comment: Поэтому формально не должно быть пар прилагательное - причастие, в противном случае будет свободное написание по авторскому разумению. Только что для однородных прилагательных это можно объяснить или для отличия от форм глагола 1.

Comment: Стало каково? Запущенно. С одной Н отвечает на другой вопрос.

Comment: А  в доме стало тихо? Какая часть речи?

Comment: Категория состояния

Comment: Переносное и прямое значения играют главную роль в причаст./прилагат. на -мый, а для страдат. причастий прош. времени это один из трёх: причастие можно заменить глаголом, не изменив сути словосочетания, подставить зависимое слово в твор.падеже, (изысканные резервы - изыскать резервы,); прилагат.  можно заменить другим прилагательным, применить степени сравнения или образовать от слово наречие на –О,  (изысканные манеры – благородные манеры, крайне изысканные манеры, изысканно); прилагательное обычно в  переносном знач. (открытая (страдат. при. прош.вр. ) дверь – открытое (прил. лицо).

Comment: Запущенный дом - дом в плохом состоянии, грязный и старый (перен.зн.).Запущенный старыми хозяевами дом - причастие (его запустили).Дело в том, что омоним запустить - привести в запустение - уже имеет переносный смысл, поэтому этот признак нельзя учитывать при разграничении, стоит обратиться к глагольности: его запустили - причастие, он старый и грязный -прилагательное.